# Select between two dates with Django

Tags: python, django

I am looking to make a query that selects between dates with Django.

I know how to do this with raw SQL pretty easily, but how could this be achieved using the Django ORM?

This is where I want to add the between dates of 30 days in my query:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(-30)
context[self.varname] = self.model._default_manager.filter(
    current_issue__isnull=True
    ).live().order_by('-created_at')
```

Answer (score 285, accepted):

Use the [`__range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) operator:

```
...filter(current_issue__isnull=True, created_at__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Comment: Is the "created_at" an arbitrary field in a model or is this the databases actual log of when the record was created?

Comment: @Philip556677 It's an arbitrary field in a model. You can set the DateField's [auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) parameter to True in order to have it easily.

Answer (score 26):

[`__range`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a `DateTimeField`, Filtering with dates won’t include items on the last day.

You need to casts the value as date:

```
...filter(created_at__date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Answer (score 3):

two methods

```
.filter(created_at__range=[from_date, to_date])
```

another method

```
.filter(Q(created_at__gte=from_date)&Q(created_at__lte=to_date))
```

- gte means greater than equal
- lte means less than equal

Comment: Q Objects is unnecessary in the second method, you can write: `.filter(created_at__gte=from_date, created_at__lte=to_date)`