# Django filter events occurring today

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling to logically represent the following in a Django filter. I have an 'event' model, and a location model, which can be represented as:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Event(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.ForeignKeyField(Location)

    objects = EventManager()
```

For a given location, I want to select all events occurring today. I've tried various strategies via a 'bookings_today' method in the EventManager, but the right filter syntax eludes me:

```
class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def bookings_today(self, location_id):
        bookings = self.filter(location=location_id, start=?, end=?)
```

date() fails as this zeroes out the times, and time during the day is critical to the app, the same goes for min and max of the dates, and using them as bookends. In addition, there are multiple possible valid configurations:

```
start_date < today, end_date during today
start_date during today, end_date during today
start_date during today, end_date after today
```

Do I need to code a whole set of different options or is there a more simple and elegant method?

Comment: have a look at the range operator for BETWEEN sql see also this answer by @danielroseman: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963201/how-do-you-select-between-two-dates-with-django

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You'll need two distinct `datetime` thresholds - `today_start` and `today_end`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

today = datetime.now().date()
tomorrow = today + timedelta(1)
today_start = datetime.combine(today, time())
today_end = datetime.combine(tomorrow, time())
```

Anything happening today must have started *before* `today_end` **and** ended *after* `today_start`, so:

```
class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def bookings_today(self, location_id):
        # Construction of today_end / today_start as above, omitted for brevity
        return self.filter(location=location_id, start__lte=today_end, end__gte=today_start)
```

(P.S. Having a `DateTimeField` (not a `DateField`) called `foo_date` is irritatingly misleading - consider just `start` and `end`...)

Comment: `datetime.now()` please

Comment: datetime.now() produce an AtrributeError

Comment: For future readers, please consider [anthony-anyanwu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3938827/anthony-anyanwu)'s answer as it is timezone aware.

Answer (score 21):

None of the answers I saw is timezone aware.

Why don't you just do this instead:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def bookings_today(self, location_id):
        bookings = self.filter(location=location_id, start__gte=timezone.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0), end__lte=timezone.now().replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59))
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use a range there like this:

```
class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def bookings_today(self, location_id):
        from datetime import datetime
        now = datetime.now()
        bookings = self.filter(location=location_id, start__lte=now, end__gte=now)
        return bookings
```

Comment: What happens if the start and end of the event falls within today? this would not pick that up - this may be a *headdesk* moment, but would putting end__gte=today and start__lte=today solve that?

Comment: Yes, you are right. end__gte=today and start__lte=today should be used.

Comment: Right, this doesn't actually work, as the start date might fall before the start of today, or after it, and date.today() doesn't appear to mesh with datetime objects in terms of equality during selection.

Comment: @jvc26: when you compare with a date (instead of a datetime), Django essentially does a range behind the scenes from 00:00 to 23:59. I've done this myself countless times, so I know it works. If you're have some issue with Aidas' code, there's some other issue at play.

Comment: @ChrisPratt but here we're comparing a datetime (datetime.now()), with a datetime (start_date), which I assume makes the time acutely relevant?

Comment: @jvc26: Wow, I had code goggles on for that one. Saw what I wanted to see I guess. Substitute `datetime.now` with `date.today` and you're golden.

Answer (score 5):

`timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).date()` gets you the correct date.

To get events occurring today(`start` today):

```
from django.utils import timezone

class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def bookings_today(self, location_id):
        t = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
        bookings = self.filter(location=location_id, start__year = t.year,
            start__month = t.month, start__day = t.day, )
```

Answer (score 2):

As it is a `DateTimeField` use `start_date__date`

```py
from django.utils import timezone

today = timezone.now().date()
leave = Event.objects.filter(start_date__date=today)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this: `pub_date__gte=datetime(2005, 1, 1)`? Use `_gte` and `__lte` to limit start and end within one day using chaining method.

Maybe something like `self.filter(start__gte=datetime(2005, 1, 1)).filter(end__lte=datetime(2005, 1, 1))`. `lte` stands for less or equal than, `gte` stands for greater or equal than.

I find it in [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups).

Answer (score 1):

I think exclude is your friend here!

```
today = datetime.date.today()
tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta( days = 1 )
self.filter( location = location_id ).exclude( end_date__lt = today ).exclude( start_date__gte = tomorrow )
```

Answer (score 1):

i have a suggestion

```
class Car:
      name = models.CharField()
      launched_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

it is very difficult to filter datetime field by todays date .
even if you take  timezone.now()  - you will not get correct output.
becuase timezone.now() has time also.

datetime field has time along with it , so even if you are giving correct date the time will not be matching.

so

> it is better to use datefield for filtering based on date

```
class Car:
      name = models.CharField()
      launched_date = models.DateField()
```

answer for the question :-

```
   from django.utils.timezone import datetime 
    today = datetime.today()
    events_for_today = Event.objects.filter(start_date__year=today.year,
                        start_date__month=today.month,
                         start_date__day=today.day)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is a `DateTimeField` use `start_date__date` and perform an [`OR (|)` query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#or)

```py
from django.db.models import Q
from django.utils import timezone

today = timezone.now().date()
qs = Event.objects.filter(
    Q(start_date__date=today) |
    Q(end_date__date=today)
)
```