# Filter all entries created today

Tags: django

I am attempting to filter all entries in a table created today, but it wont allow me to use `.date()` on the column `created`.

Here is the sourcecode for the filter:

```
StartupHistory.objects.filter(user=2).filter(created.date()=datetime.date.today())
```

**Example**

```
>>> resultset = StartupHistory.objects.filter(user=2)
>>> for element in resultset:
...     print element.created.date()
... 
2014-03-12
2014-03-12
2014-03-12
2014-03-12
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django filter events occurring today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245483/django-filter-events-occurring-today)

Comment: @alecxe, that is described in a slightly different context compared to mine.

Comment: How about `StartupHistory.objects.filter(user=2).filter(created__date=datetime.date.today())`

Comment: @karthikr, been down that road i get following error `Join on field 'created' not permitted. Did you misspell 'date' for the lookup type?`

Comment: Ok. How about just `StartupHistory.objects.filter(user=2).filter(created=datetime.date.today()‌​)` ?

Comment: created=datetime.date.today()‌ won't work if created is a datetime field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter it like this:

```
StartupHistory.objects.filter(user=2).filter(created__startswith=datetime.date.today())
```

Comment: i tried a few different things and this was the most accurate thanks