# How to get current events in queryset?

Tags: python, django

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    stop = models.DateTimeField()

now = timezone.now() # 08:30 am
qs = Event.objects.filter(start__gte=now) #but this exclude `event1`
```

Events objects:

```
name   start             stop
event1 20.11.2015 08:15  20.11.2015 09:30
event2 20.11.2015 09:30  20.11.2015 10:25
```

What is the **best** way to get events including the currently ongoing?

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245483/django-filter-events-occurring-today

Comment: @Anush yes, but not include hours - this is important in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
now = timezone.now()
qs = Event.objects.filter(start__lte=now, end__gte=now)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to Anush, you probably want to try the following:

```
now = timezone.now().date()
qs = Event.objects.filter(
   start__year__lte=now.year,
   start__month__lte=now.month,
   start__day__lte=now.day,
)
```

Unfortunately the current stable django version (1.8) does not provide the ability to truncate datetime fields to dates, which is why you need to specify year, month and day seperately.

The latest dev version as of this post's writing (1.9) provides the [`__date` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date) which should solve this.