# django get data with filter today

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-templates, aggregate

i want to get Device created today
this is my model :

```
class Device(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=dtype, null=True)
    ipadress = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

and i tried this views but didn't work :

```
device_today = Device.objects.filter(date_created=today).count()
```

any advice ?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245483/django-filter-events-occurring-today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
import datetime
today=datetime.date.today()
Device.objects.filter(date_created__date=today)
```