# Django queryset based on comparing dates

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you select between two dates with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963201/how-do-you-select-between-two-dates-with-django)

I have django model that contains 2 fields - **c_date** and **c_int**. As I am really weak in creating queries... is there some way to fetch from db only those records that fulfill this: `c_date+timedelta(days=c_int)=date.today`? I would like to do it on DB level because it would be faster than fetching all records and comparing date for all of them.

Comment: not really because comparision is based on two values from DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`QuerySet.extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) for constructing complex `WHERE` clauses. For your requirement in particular, you should check the availability of the [`DATEADD`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp) function for your database of choice.

Although, depending on how big your data set is and how often you'd need to run this query, another option is to do a migration and simply compute the sum of the date and offset immediately as an instance is created--you can create a custom `ModelForm` to continue allowing user's to specify `c_int` as an offset in days.

Comment: That's it! Unfortunatelly in my server there was no DATEADD function but I handled it with simpler SQL query:
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (c_date+INTERVAL c_int)="2012-08-02";