# how to filter given two datefields if they coincide with a from and to date in a model django

Tags: python, django

I have a 2 dates from 2 datepickers
date1 = '2013-01-22'
date2 = '2013-01-28'
and I have a model like this

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField()
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()
```

What I am tasked to do is to know if some of the dates **between** date1 and date2 is between those from_date and to_date (same item)

so for example if i have a from_date of '2013-01-24' and to_date '2013-01-27', some of the dates from input date1 and date2 (which are the days 24 25 26 27) are included and prompts true.

It's like an intersection. Any queries?

a gte on from_date and lte on to_date doesn't work since date1 is less than from date and date2 is greater than to date

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you select between two dates with Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963201/how-do-you-select-between-two-dates-with-django)

Comment: I think not. it's like a range from a range. __range is for 1 field in the model only. i'm comparing two date inputs here from two datefields in the model. 
date1 and date2 is a date range. that means is is from january 22 upto 28.

Comment: I misread that - my apologies :(

Comment: lol sorry for that. i should have used "between" tho for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a math question. This query should do the trick:

```
date1 <= to_date and date2 >= from_date
```

**Edit**

The following django statement should give you the desired result:

```
SampleModel.objects.filter(to_date__gte=date1, from_date__lte=date2)
```

Comment: but how can I query an "and"?

Comment: According to the django docs, you also can filter for more than one constraint: `SampleModel.objects.filter(to_date__gte=date1, from_date__lte<=date2)`. This is more efficient than filtering twice.